# For the Label control, why does the text rise a little when its length exceeds the width of the control? Is there a way to avoid it?(C#,winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, label, controls

I tried "AutoEllipsis" and "AutoSize", but they didn't work.
I uploaded a GIF picture to help you understand my problems:

[image]

It seems GIF picture can not display.I add two more picture here:
[image]
[image]

Note that the height of the text is different.

Example Code:

```
public void Run()
{
    Form form = new Form();
    form.Width = (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 0.15);
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Width = form.Width;
    lbl.Height = 200;
    lbl.Text = "this is a test,this is a test,this is a test,this is a test,this is a test";
    lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    form.Height = lbl.Height;
    form.Controls.Add(lbl);
    form.SizeChanged += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) =>
    {
        lbl.Width = form.Width;
    });
    form.Show();
}
```

But when I test this example code, I already know the answer. The key point is "lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft". This code makes the text center in the vertical direction. When the width of the Label is reduced, the text will become two lines, and the position of the first line will become higher.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you also tried to set min and max size after turning auto size off?

Comment: Where does the dropdown symbol come from? Try that example without a container for the label and put a label directly on the form and see if it still behaves that way. If not check what the container does.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Jmcilhinney and Ralf for your advice, really help me.

when I test this example code, I already know the answer. The key point is "lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft". This code makes the text center in the vertical direction. When the width of the Label is reduced, the text will become two lines, and the position of the first line will become higher.